# Facebook app display all comments from all not just friends

Tags: php, javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api

Hi I've just built a facebook app which appeared to be working correctly.

The app allows users to submit messages of support and then displays once the user has granted permission.

The app looked to be working, my friends/colleges tested it (all of whom I'm friends with on FB) and each of their messages appeared.

However I can see other posts are being added but I can't see them but the person who is posting can.

Is there a way to get around this?

Comment: Hi Brob maybe a code snippet how the messages are being handled and displayed would be helpful or can you please give us the link to your app?

Comment: Hi David, here is the code http://pastebin.com/UrqLGsm5 its taking a user defined message and posting it but I can only view posts by friends and not everyone

Comment: I know almost nothing about java script, but the "problem" might be in privacy settings, the message might be shares, however you can't see it because you are not friend with the user therefore you can't see the posted message.